# FirewallD Order of Zone Evaluation

Tags: firewalld

I spent a couple hours today attempting to setup a firewall rule for SSH access. I have multiple custom zones as shown below. I've changed most of the IP addresses for security reasons.

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
web-zone
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 160.1.100.0/21 10.0.0.0/8 194.1.1.0/24
ssh
  sources: 194.1.1.3
admin
  sources: 160.1.1.3
etranscripts
  sources: 55.164.111.101 55.164.84.100

web-zone (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 160.1.100.0/21 10.0.0.0/8 194.1.1.0/24
  services: 
  ports: 9060/tcp 9070/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

ssh (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 194.1.1.3
  services: 
  ports: 22/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

From these rules, one would think that I could ssh into the server from 194.1.1.3, but I can't. Stranger still, if I change the zone that the network interface is bound to, I can ssh into the server.

```
[root@dev-banapp03 ~]# firewall-cmd --remove-interface=eth0 --zone=web-zone --permanent
The interface is under control of NetworkManager, setting zone to default.
success
[root@dev-banapp03 ~]# firewall-cmd --add-interface=eth0 --zone=ssh --permanent
The interface is under control of NetworkManager, setting zone to 'ssh'.
success
[root@dev-banapp03 ~]# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
web-zone
  sources: 160.1.100.0/21 10.0.0.0/8 194.1.1.0/24
ssh
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 194.1.1.3
admin
  sources: 160.1.1.3
etranscripts
  sources: 55.164.111.101 55.164.84.100
```

Obviously, there is some kind of order applied to the zone evaluation, but I don't know what it is, and I haven't found any good articles on it. Can anyone here tell me what's going on?

~ Bob

Answer (score 1):

order of processing within the active zones

interface, source ip, default zone...